# Is there a way to exclude package-level functions and members from Doxygen output?

Tags: java, documentation, static, doxygen

I'm working with Doxygen at the workplace and am having a problem with the Java code. With the EXTRACT_ALL=NO, EXTRACT_PRIVATE=NO, EXTRACT_STATIC=NO, EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES=NO, and EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS=NO, the output still includes static members that are not defined as public or private.

EX. Let's say I have the following code:

```
class EXAMPLE{

public static func1()

private static func2()

static func3()

}
```

`func3` is defined only as `static` because it is a package-level function.

`func1` and `func3` show up in the output, and I only want `func1` to appear.

Does anyone know a way to show only those functions explicitly defined as public?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can put stuff that you don't want to see in doxygen output inside a `\cond ... \endcond` block:

```
class EXAMPLE{

public static func1()

/// \cond

private static func2()
static func3()

/// \endcond

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my situation is a bit more complicated. Let's say that the one's I don't want to show are thoroughly mixed in with the ones I do want to show. For example, every other function is declared only as static. Using those \cond blocks would get very tedious very fast. I'm looking more along the lines of being able to change properties in the config file without having to muddle up the code with extra comments needed only for the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Developping some new filters for Doxygen (HTML, XSLT, BAT..., see https://github.com/msillano/filters_dox) I create many pseudo-function having the same name. The file pages are ok, but that makes the pages 'File Members/all' and 'File Members/Functions' without any interest. 
In Doxygen-config it is not possible to exclude the creation of that pages (shame). I found a workaround for HTML output (on ver. 1.8.15).

- Set expert/HTML/HTML_DYNAMIC_MENUS to 'yes'.
- Build the documentation.
- Edit the files 'navtreedata.js' (for tree menu) and 'menudata.js'   (for tab menu). Using a editor with 'parenthesis match' it is easy to delete all items after 'File List'.

Not elegant, but it works.